# How to Hide HTML Table Row in Outlook Mail Application

Tags: html

I have generated an HTML file and embed(for quick view rather than click the attachment), and attach (for further analysis) to mail and send. During embedding, it was expected to hide one table row, which used to filter values as embed mode doesn't support interaction. While I need to have the feature on attachment mode.

I go through following approaches none of them works fine for my case

1. https://litmus.com/community/discussions/889-hide-show-td-in-gmail-outlook-yahoo
2. https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/how-to-code-emails-for-outlook-2016/

I have tried the below css to use in tr and th/td respectively

```
.hide {
        max-height:0;
        display:none;
        mso-hide:all;
        overflow:hidden;
        font-size:0;
    }
```

but it hides in both places.

Are there any ways to show in attachment HTML and not show in embedded one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally sorted this out by using a toggle option where `display:none` is activated by the button click. Though it still can be obtained at the manual embedding of HTML email attachment. It won't appear on the HTML which embedded inside the m